# why datagridview's row leave or cell leave event not allowing addnewrow()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form in which i have one txtbox, one datagridview and one button for save .

now as value is entered in textbox, related values will be filled in datagridview ( i am manually calling `datagridview.addnewrow()` as `dgv.allowadd = false` for my application )

now i want that instead of focus going to save button I want the focus on textbox again ! so as to enter other value and on datagridview one more row will be added from `dgv.addnewrow()`

as i set the focus manually on textbox with `dgv.rowLeave` Event or `dgv.cellLeave` event `> dgv.addnewrow()` is not working for the 2nd time `addnewrow()` . It is overwritting the 1st added row

`addnewrow()` works fine all time as i enter value in textbox if i writes the code in `dgv.leave` Event

so if anyone can Help me to achieve this functionality!

```
    private void TxtPACKET_NO_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       // on key enter fetch the packet information 
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
         if (txtBARCODE.Text.Length > 0)
           {
             FetchData(txtBARCODE.Text);
           }
       }
    }
   private void FetchData(string PacketNo)
   {
      DataRowView drv = dgvGRADE_DET_PS.AddNewRow();
      drv.BeginEdit();
      // Assigning Necessary Values to the columns
     drv.EndEdit();
     this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.CurrentCell = this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.Rows[this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3];
   }

    void dgvGRADE_DET_PS_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MY COLUMN NAME")
        {
            this.txtBARCODE.Text = string.Empty;
            this.txtBARCODE.Select();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your code? dgv.Focus() ? Did you also set the dgv.CurrentCell? ((Also: Please watch your spelling!))

Comment: yes. i do set the current cell from coding for my requirement. and i am using textbox.focus() on dgv.cellleave() event

Comment: Well, you probably just need to add a  `textbox.Focus()` at the end of the button's `Click` event.. What did you set the `CurrentCell` to be? A Cell in the new row?

Comment: void dgvGRADE_DET_PS_CellLeave(object sender,DataGridCellEventArgs e)
        {

           this.txtBARCODE.Text = string.Empty;
           this.txtBARCODE.Select();
        } and for the datagridview's new row : this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.CurrentCell = this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.Rows[this.dgvGRADE_DET_PS.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3];

Comment: plus i want focus from dgv to previous control textbox : i dont want the save button to get focus after dgv looses focus

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code. You can code the focus to go wherever you want. Are you sure you want to code the CellLeave unconditionally, i.e. without checking which cell you are leaving? - Of course nobody can help you with you addnewrow code as you don't show. Also: Please correct the spelling!

Comment: ofcourse i do check the cell condition to check if last cell then only set focus to textbox